# Adding some value on top of stacked barplot - Bars disappear when defining aes(y) in geom_text

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to produce a stacked barplot and the percentage change between the years on top of the stacked bars.

My data:

```
my_data <- structure(list(year = c(2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2017, 2017, 2017, 
2017, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2020, 2020, 
2020, 2020, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021), some_data = c(700.884929, 
123.61278, 91.331399, 5.800863, 709.664147, 5.255171, 125.568917, 
94.289424, 721.353624, 2.440006, 130.295319, 96.372448, 726.963262, 
0.875374, 129.695907, 97.54507, 764.370595, 0.876399, 126.677571, 
105.180633, 801.974246, 0.787544, 131.254017, 109.521045), some_letters = c("B", 
"A", "D", "C", "B", "C", "A", "D", "B", "C", "A", "D", "B", "C", 
"A", "D", "B", "C", "A", "D", "B", "C", "A", "D")), row.names = c(NA, 
-24L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Percentage change information:

```
for_label <- structure(list(year = c(2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021), 
    pct_change = c(NA, 0.0142656905848388, 0.0167780411191876, 
    0.00485892011456412, 0.0440021799523009, 0.0465664546661004
    ), my_pos = c(921629971, 934777659, 950461397, 955079613, 
    997105198, 1043536852)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Now I try to plot the data and add the percentages:

```
library(tidyverse)

my_data %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = year, y = some_data, fill = some_letters))+
  geom_bar(position = "stack", stat = "identity") +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = 2016:2021)+
  geom_text(
    data = for_label,
    aes(x = year, y = pct_change, label = percent(pct_change), fill = NULL), 
    position = "stack")
```

However, the values are on on the bottom of the plot:

[image: Percentages on the bottom]

Alternatively I change the `pct_change` to `my_pos` in `geom_text(aes(y = ))`. Then I get the percentages at the right position but the bars disappear. How to solve this problem? I tried to play around with `position = position_stack()` but never got it to work.

[image: Bars dissapear]

Comment: I suggest you use `annotate()` command from ggplot2. Here you have a link: https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/annotate.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll first combine `my_data` and `for_label` into a single dataframe before plotting, then they can use the same `data` in `ggplot`.

This method will give labels in every stacked portion of `some_letters`, we can use a `ifelse` statement to only include label for `A` so that the labels are on top.

```
left_join(my_data, for_label, by = "year") %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = year, y = some_data, fill = some_letters))+
  geom_bar(position = "stack", stat = "identity") +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = 2016:2021)+
  geom_text(aes(label = ifelse(some_letters == "A", percent(pct_change), NA), fill = NULL), 
    position = "stack", check_overlap = T, vjust = -4)
```

[image: label_stacked_bar]